# Don't show console.logs with ng build -prod --aot

Tags: angular

This is how I build my Angular 2 app for production:

```
ng build -prod --aot
```

I have a lot of `console.log` statements. How do I hide those in a production build?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all console.log inside your code ? It's a bad thing to keep your console log after you finish a function

simple fix. but 'bad fix'. Put this code in main.ts

```
if(env === 'prod') { // assuming you have env variable configured
   window.console.log = function(){};
}
```